# search in nested map C++

Tags: c++11, stl, hashmap, containers

I have a nested map:

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,float>> registration_by_date_time;
```

where the key is a string for the date and the value is another map with key a string for time end value a float.

I have to implement this method:

```
float get_registration(const string & date, const string & time) const;
```

which returns the time series value at date and time or "NaN" in case the value was not previously added in
the time series.

My implementation is the following:

```
float get_registration(const string & date, const string & time) const{
    if(registration_by_date_time.find(date) != registration_by_date_time.cend())
        if(registration_by_date_time.at(date).find(time) != registration_by_date_time.at(date).cend())
            return registration_by_date_time[date][time];
        else
            return "NaN";
    else
        return "NaN";
}
```

Is it correct? in particular I wold like to know if I am using correctly .at and if I also could use the access operator [] or "second".

Comment: Do you really need nested maps? Most often it is enough to use `std::tuple` of two or more keys, and it is certainly enough for he piece of code as shown. You would be using something like `registration_by_date_time->find({date, time})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the index operator for map is not a constant operation (for `std::map` access is O(log(n))). So here you pay this cost twice - once for the find and second time to return the value (if available). A better approach is to store the result of find:

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,float>>::iterator by_date_it = registration_by_date_time.find(date);
// or auto by_date_it = registration_by_date_time.find(date);
if (by_date != registration_by_date_time.end()) {
  std::map<std::string,float>::iterator by_time = by_date_it->second.find(time);
  if (by_time != by_date_it->end()) {
    return by_time->second;
  }
}
return "NaN;
```

As pointed out, not only is this code shorter but it should be faster, avoiding double access with cost `O(log(n))` for both the outer and the inner map. In general as I suggest you can use auto here to make the code shorter, I have written out the type explicitly in hope to make the logic clearer.

NOTE: std::map is not implemented with a hashmap, it is implemented with red-black trees (a type of binary search tree), so it is possible this is what led you to think the complexity of access is with expected constant complexity.

Comment: This is exactly the solution proposed by the professor, but I wold like to know if my code works. I am trying to understand if I am using correctly .at

Comment: I believe the most important point is about the multiple search over the container, which will make your code slower. For the outer map you perform 3 access (1 for `find`, 2 for `.at`), for the inner you do two - one for the find and 1 for the access.

Comment: @Fabio regarding your question for `at` -  the most important difference between at and the index operator (with `[]`) is the behavior when the object is not present in the container (`at` would throw an exception, while `[]` would insert a new element). As you've already verified its presence both would do the same.

Comment: In c++ there is important difference between the two. `.` is used when you access a member or method of an object, `->` is used to access a member or method *of a pointer to an object*. Just as a pointer is not the actual object, an iterator to is not the object that is pointed to by it, for that reason the operator `->` is used to access the members or methods of the objects that the iterator points to